# Problem writing and then reading the same Excel file using Openpyxl

Tags: python, excel

I am trying to write cell B20 of sheet named "Data" in a workbook named "Mainfile.xlsm". After that I want to save the workbook and read the value of cell C89 in the same workbook's worksheet named "results" . Note that C89 contains a formula. I want to print the (value only) result from C89. I have successfully written the data in Cell B20 and saved it but I dont know how to read C89 value from the saved version of this workbook. Bcz it returns the formula when i do so and not the cell value. I have tried the wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('Mainfile.xlsm', read_only=False, keep_vba=True,data_only=True)
but it returns None.

Please note that data is entered through entry box opress_entry

Here is my code. Please help.

```
        wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('Excelfile.xlsm', read_only=False, keep_vba=True)
        sh1 = wb["Data"]
        sh2 = wb["results"]
        # Write on excel spreadsheet at particular location
        sh1["B20"].value = float(opress_entry.get())
        # save the file
        wb.save('Excelfile.xlsm')
        wb.close()
        print(sh2["C89"].value)
        # set focus on the metertag field
        opress_entry.focus_set()
```

Comment: I was able to replicate your issue with above code, but by adding ````data_only=True````, the print statement gave the value of C89. Of course, I don't have ````opress_entry````. So, either it should work or try without ````opress_entry``` part of the code.

Comment: Hi I know it works with data_value true but problem comes when I try to save it because my actual file contain formulas and vba as well so if I save an opened workbook with data value true and then save it it creates a mess in it